# Creating a dictionary based on a word

Tags: python

In Python, how would I go about creating a dictionary that whose keys are a letter followed by another letter, and whose values are a set of the letters that directly follow that letter in the word?

For example, the word `'apple'` would give back `{a:{'p'}, p:{'p', 'l'}, l:{'e'}}`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, do add some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_word="apple"
d = defaultdict(list)
for a,b in zip(my_word,my_word[1:]):
   d[a].append(b)
```

maybe?... `collections.Counter` might be usefull as well